# Basic tree recursion in Clojure

Tags: clojure, tree

I was wondering if anybody could help me, as I've hit a block with this code. My code is featured below.

When I run a trace it keeps stopping when a nil value is hit, does anybody have any idea what is wrong?

This is my data:

```
'(1 ( -2 17 (4)) -8 (6 13)))
```

And the code:

```
(defn tree? [t]
  (and (seq t) (not (empty? t))))

(defn bounds2
  ([tree] (bounds2 tree 99 -99))
  ([tree minVal maxVal]
   (cond
     (number? tree) tree
     (tree? tree)
     (cond

       (nil? (bounds2 (first tree) minVal maxVal))
       (bounds2 (rest tree) minVal maxVal)

       ((complement nil?) (bounds2 (first tree) minVal maxVal))
       (cond
         (< (bounds2 (first tree) minVal maxVal) minVal)
         (recur (rest tree) (first tree) maxVal)

         (> (bounds2 (first tree) minVal maxVal) maxVal)
         (recur (rest tree) minVal (first tree)))

       (empty? tree) nil))))
```

Comment: What are you expecting the result to be?

Comment: Sorry, I really should of specified that. I am looking for the min and max values of the data tree fed in. I'm aware flatten exists, and would be the logical way to approach this, but am trying to avoid using that for this function.

Comment: BTW, your `tree?` function is redundant. `(not (empty? t))` is the same as `(not (not (seq t)))` which is the same as `seq`. Just replace `tree?` by `seq` and eliminate that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems here.  The most immediate one is that you never actually return any bounds.  Every possible exit point from your `cond` statements is either some variety of unmodified recursive call, a number, or `nil`.  Logically you need to return something like `[minVal maxVal]` at some point, and you should be expecting all of your recursive calls to return something in that format.  Of course this will complicate your comparison logic quite a bit.

Other important points include the fact that `tree?` is logically equivalent to `seq` (as was pointed out in the comments), and your `(empty? tree)` clause is dead code, since `tree` can never satisfy both `tree?` = `seq` and `empty?`.  (As it turns out, `(bounds2 '())` still returns `nil`, but this is because `cond` returns `nil` if you fall through without matching any clause.)

If you'll forgive the total rewrite, I think this does what you want, in pretty much the same way as your original code.  (You mentioned in the comments that you don't want to use `flatten`, so I avoided both that and the intermediate `reduce` solution).

```lisp
(defn bounds2 [tree]
  (loop [[x & more :as tree] tree, minVal 99, maxVal -99]
    (cond
      (empty? tree)  [minVal maxVal]
      (number? x)    (recur more (min x minVal) (max x maxVal))
      (seq x)        (recur (concat x more) minVal maxVal))))
```

Most of my changes are stylistic (the use of `loop` rather than multiple arities; destructuring; un-nesting the `cond` statements); the one major change in logic here is that we're using `concat` to "`flatten` as we go".  It is also important to note that using `recur` for all of our recursive calls will help protect us from blowing the stack.

Comment: Thank you very much mate! Works perfectly. I'll have to have a further study of what you've done to fully grasp it, but it's great.